# Is there a shortcut for reviewing suggested edits?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, review

I was just about to edit a post full of errors when I saw that there was already an edit waiting for approval that covered about 95% of what I was going to do.

Is there any shortcut where I can review these edits? It would make sense to put it into the "review" bar...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [review tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) for suggested edits, but unfortunately you don't have [enough rep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) to use it yet, which is why the tab doesn't show up for you. 5k users can go there to approve edits, and 10k users get a notification in the top bar, so they're usually handled pretty quickly:

[Screenshot of the top bar notification http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-suggested-edits-indicator.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/unix-suggested-edits-indicator.png)

Comment: I can review (I seem to have enough REP for that), but am not able to see the tab? Does that make sense?

Comment: @Nils It is kind of strange (you need 2k to review edits, but 5k to see them in one place), but a lot of the moderation tools are like that. The 10k tools are mostly lists of things, like posts with pending close votes, even though you only need 3k to vote to close

Comment: I just looked that up - that TAB seems to be linked to the wiki-edit priviledge (5K rep). So should I turn my question into a change request in your opinion?

Comment: @Nils I doubt it'll get changed. You might want to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80070/145982)

Comment: I see. Caleb`s comment to that question probably hits the mark. On UL I review every new question anyway. Something that is not possible on SF...